# Add files to existing apk with zip command

Tags: android

I use the zip command below to add the files to the existing apk.

```
zip t.apk assets/more.txt
```

The file is added to the apk. But it always fails when install modified app on android mobile. Is it possible to add the files with the zip command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apk needs to be signed (with the same key) and zipaligned every time it's updated.

Explained here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html and a related question [Android: How to manually add a file to apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535728/android-how-to-manually-add-a-file-to-apk)